# Opening Big encrypted pdf files stored on sdcard

Tags: android, pdf, encryption

In my project I am using custom android devices and I have to encrypt all the files on my sdcard for security. I am using AES-128 bit encryption, but it takes too long to decrypt and open the files.

For the videos I have used on the fly decryption using `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream` and a proxy server. Is this possible for big pdf files?

A 12 MB pdf file is taking around 40 seconds to decrypt so opening the file after completely decrypting it is not an option. Also, I do not want to save the decrypted files anywhere on the device. Is it possible to open parts of pdf files as done with videos?

I tried  using the full disk encryption in android but it did not work on my custom devices and showed only a green droid, after which nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just encrypted the whole file and your viewer app/library expects to get a whole file, not really. If you used PDF encryption, which encrypts each object inside the file, you could decrypt and display them on demand.

What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are those files part of your app? If you just want to protect data on the SD card, there are ways to do this automatically, but they require a rooted device. For example [LUKS Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager).

Comment: Yes those files are part of my app.I have custom android devices and I want these files to be viewed only through these devices. I am encrypting files  so that user cannot copy them to other devices.

As mentioned I am using AES-128 bit encryption for all the files.

Comment: And where is the key stored? If it is on the device, they could always extract it and decrypt the files.

Comment: The user will be entering some PIN or password which would be used for decrypting the key first and then the main content will be available. The encrypted key is stored at some temporary location in the device.

Comment: Well that makes sense. But with this setup, your best bet is probably to split the PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was testing on the emulator. On actual device the time taken to decrypt is much less(~6sec for 12 MB) and acceptable.Finally I did the following :-

For videos and audio I used streaming to mxPlayer. For the big files which cannot be shown in parts I encrypted only parts of the file. Encrypting around 10MB of the file makes it unusable.

The files are saved to some hidden temporary location which is deleted once its no longer required.

Still proper apps are required on the device so that Android can detect them and open them when required. Like some video players didn't work when opening video from my application but mxPlayer did.